# Expandable Animation menu

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build an application and I like very much the H&M menu. Anyone can help me with some ideas how to build this kind of menu on android?

It’s an expandable menu which  appear when you click on the H&M Logo.

http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/7509/hmmenu.png

Answer (score 0):

The best way to go about this is implementing a [Custom View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) in your application.

What I would recommend is to develop a ViewStub that you can drop-in and populate whenever the user presses the button.  This way, you can reuse it across screens, and there is only one thing to change if you need to add/remove an item.

Hope this helps!